# Iterate over one dataframe and add values to another dataframe without "append" or "concat"?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iterator, append, concatenation

I have a dataframe "df_edges" where I want to iterate over.
Inside the iteration is an if/else and a string split. I need to add the values from the if/else into a new dataframe (each iteration = one new row in the other dataframe).

Example data of "df_edges":

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| channelId ... featuredChannelsUrlsCount |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 0  UC-ry8ngUIJHTMBWeoARZGmA  ... 1      |
| 1  UC-zK3cJdazy01AKTu8g_amg  ... 6      |
| 2  UC05_iIGvXue0sR01JNpRHzw  ... 10     |
| 3  UC141nSav5cjmTXN7B70ts0g  ... 0      |
| 4  UC1cQzKmbx9x0KipvoCt4NJg  ... 0      |
```

+-----------------------------------------+

```
# new empty dataframe where I want to add the values
df_edges_to_db = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Source", "Target"])

#iteration over the dataframe
for row in df_edges.itertuples():
    if row.featuredChannelsUrlsCount != 0:
        featured_channels = row[2].split(',')
        for fc in featured_channels:
            writer.writerow([row[1], fc])
            df_edges_to_db = df_edges_to_db.append({"Source": row[1], "Target": fc}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        writer.writerow([row[1], row[1]])
        df_edges_to_db = df_edges_to_db.append({"Source": row[1], "Target": row[1]}, ignore_index=True)
```

This seems to work. But the documentation says (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

> The following, while not recommended methods for generating DataFrames

So, is there a more "best practice" way (besides append/concat) to add the rows with the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible create list of dictionaries by `python append`, not [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) like in your solution, and the call only once `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = []
#iteration over the dataframe
for row in df_edges.itertuples():
    if row.featuredChannelsUrlsCount != 0:
        featured_channels = row[2].split(',')
        for fc in featured_channels:
            writer.writerow([row[1], fc])
            L.append({"Source": row[1], "Target": fc})
    else:
        writer.writerow([row[1], row[1]])
        L.append({"Source": row[1], "Target": row[1]})

df_edges_to_db = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not clear how your **df_edges** dataFrame looks like. By looking your code I will suggest you to replace your body of outer for-loop with something like this :

```
new_list= [someOperationOn(x) if x==0 else otherOperationOn(x) for x in mylist]
```

Comment: Added df_edges.head() example data